# How to write test cases for Simple Users and Super Users in Django

Tags: python, django, selenium, django-testing

I want to write test cases in Django to check which user is a `simple user`, and which is `SuperUser` and came across this code:

```
    def test_login_user(self):
        self.selenium.get('%s%s' % (self.live_server_url, '/login/'))
        username_input = self.selenium.find_element_by_name("username")
        username_input.send_keys('testuser')
        password_input = self.selenium.find_element_by_name("password")
        password_input.send_keys('testpass')
        self.selenium.find_element_by_xpath('//button[@type="submit"]').click()
        #password_input.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)

    def test_login_staff(self):
        self.selenium.get('%s%s' % (self.live_server_url, '/login/'))
        username_input = self.selenium.find_element_by_name("username")
        username_input.send_keys('testadmin')
        password_input = self.selenium.find_element_by_name("password")
        password_input.send_keys('testpass')
```

I code is running fine in my project but my question is how you return `False` here, when we enter some invalid login credentials. Currently, even if I pass some invalid username and password, it is not showing anything.

```
My fixture : fixtures = [{"fields": {"username": "rakesh", "first_name": "", "last_name": "", "is_active": True, "is_superuser": True, "is_staff": True, "last_login": "2015-10-17T20:20:37.455Z", "groups": [], "user_permissions": [], "password": "pbkdf2_sha256$20000$1tGw8u4pGPxD$WmJVx9QDjFx0xZHq5vt/XgPXjYYvRn2tARyTzQ6RRYg=", "email": "rakesh.sukla53@gmail.com", "date_joined": "2015-10-06T19:02:04.044Z"}, "model": "auth.user", "pk": 1}]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When doing selenium tests the standard practice is to check for the presence or absence of certain elements. However you cannot test if user is staff by visiting the login url, you will have to visit the '/admin/login/' url which is the place where a super user or staff user logs into the admin console. Thus your test might become:

```
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException

def test_login_staff(self):
    self.selenium.get('%s%s' % (self.live_server_url, '/admin/login/'))
    username_input = self.selenium.find_element_by_name("username")
    username_input.send_keys('testadmin')
    password_input = self.selenium.find_element_by_name("password")
    password_input.send_keys('testpass')
    time.sleep(3)
    self.assertRaises(NoSuchElementException,  self.driver.find_element_by_name,"username")
```

The above code asserts that the staff login has succeeded. If on the other hand you wanted to check that the staff login has failed, the code should be

```
self.assertTrue(self.driver.find_element_by_name,"username")
```

On a side note, I would advice agains using `self.selenium` as a variable name, might be confusing since the library is also called selenium. May I suggest you use `self.driver` instead?

Update:
If you are testing whether the user is a super user or staff, you might want to assert that condition before starting off selenium

```
u = User.objects.get(username = 'testadmin')
self.assertTrue(u.is_staff)
self.assertTrue(u.is_superuser)
```

Comment: Thank you so much. This content is very helpful :)

Comment: I am passing the correct `username` and `password` in my test_login_staff but it is showing `Django administration
Please enter the correct username and password for a staff account. Note that both fields may be case-sensitive.
Username:
Password:`

Comment: yes, that is as I mentioned the proper link to test for super user and admin. Merely login through the normal page doesn't distinguish between super users and normal users. You need to goto the admin login page for that.

Comment: I tested `username` and `password` on admin page but still it is showing invalid

Comment: is that a valid staff and super user account? You might want to assert that before you start. Updating my answer.

Comment: Not able to understand why it is saying `u.is_staff` is not true where my admin username is `rakesh` and password is `ranjan` :/

Comment: Please check the updated question. I even added the fixture json file, and you can clearly see my username and password is superuser.

Comment: If your admin username is rakesh why are you doing username_input.send_keys('testadmin')  ? that should be username_input.send_keys('rakesh')

Comment: I am passing `testuser - rakesh` and `testpass - ranjan`. That is just a sample code I gave

Comment: You can see my test case `https://gist.github.com/rakeshsukla53/613d5c7cf2967ff05b84`

Comment: when posting on stackoverflow it's always adviced to post the exact code. To avoid confusions like this.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/92637/discussion-between-rakesh-ranjan-sukla-and-e4c5).